# ToC after chapter configuration

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

The following `mwe` example showcases some issues that I am currently facing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ToC formt of book is affecting mini ToC intended to go after each chapter
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \newlength\mychaplength
    \settowidth\mychaplength{\bfseries\sffamily Effect on TOC\quad} % calculate width of indentation for chapter heading

    \titlecontents{section}
                [\mychaplength]
                {}
                {{\thecontentslabel}\enskip}
                {}
                {\hfill\contentspage}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\noindent
        \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}%
            \noindent         
            TEMP TOC~\hrulefill
            {\begingroup%
                \startcontents[chapters]%
                \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
            \endgroup%
            }%
        \end{minipage}
\newpage
\section{Algebra, Geometry and Statistics.}
\section{Some random section that is long.}
\end{document}
```

In the process of creating a mini ToC for every chapter, I ran into a problem. For some reason or the other the settings I have in my main ToC are affecting the current ToC for the first chapter. Note that the settings for the main ToC are necessary for some spacing requirements I need. How can I restore/redefine or create a new settings for the mini ToC. What is necessary to be done?

[image]

On another note, is it possible to only have the section number like `1` and `2` instead of `1.1` and `1.2` and,

Is it possible to remove the page numbers and dotted line from the mini ToC?

---

Ultimately, I am looking for three possible configurations:

1. Restore the ToC locally to create the new mini ToC without it being affected by the main ToC. Default ToC settings.

[image]

2. Section numbering does not have the chapter numbering; `1` instead of `1.1` and,

[image]

3. Remove dotted lines and page number and leave only section number and section title.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\titlecontents` in the context of the minitoc.

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ToC formt of book is affecting mini ToC intended to go after each chapter
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newlength\mychaplength
% calculate width of indentation for chapter heading
\settowidth{\mychaplength}{whatever} % for main toc

\titlecontents{section}[\mychaplength]
  {}
  {\thecontentslabel\enskip}
  {}
  {\hfill\contentspage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myminitoc}{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
  \titlecontents{section}[2em]
    {}
    {\thecontentslabel\enskip}
    {}
    {}%
  % save the value of tocdepth
  \chardef\savedtocdepth=\value{tocdepth}%
  % redefine \numberline
  \let\savedcontentsline\contentsline
  \def\contentsline##1##2##3{%
    \begingroup
    \let\numberline\numberlinegobble
    \protected@edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\savedcontentsline{##1}{##2}{}}\x
  }%
  % the minitoc proper
  TEMP TOC~\hrulefill
  \startcontents[chapters]
  \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
  % restore the value of tocdepth
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{\savedtocdepth}
  \end{minipage}\newpage
}
\newcommand{\numberlinegobble}[1]{\numberline@gobble#1\@nil}
\def\numberline@gobble#1.#2\@nil{\noexpand\numberline{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\myminitoc

\section{Algebra, Geometry and Statistics.}
\section{Some random section that is long.}

\end{document}
```

I used a dirty trick for removing the chapter number, via a redefinition of `\numberline`. However `titletoc` redefines itself `\numberline`, so we need to act before control is taken by `titletoc`.

Note also that I saved the value of tocdepth, because `\setcounter` acts globally.

[image]

Some words of comment.

The package `titletoc` redefines `\contentsline` which, in turn, redefines `\numberline` each time. So my idea of redefining `\numberline` to gobble the first dot together with what precedes it didn't work. So I resorted to an indirect method.

I locally save the current definition of `\contentsline` in `\savedcontentsline`. Then I redefine `\contentsline` to open a group, redefine locally `\numberline` to do the job described above; the new definition of `\contentsline` will just push on the input stream the same tokens as before, with the exception of `\contentsline` that becomes `\savedcontentsline` and the argument to `\numberline` that will have been reduced. This way, `titletoc` will do its work as if nothing had happened.

How's the new `\numberline` defined? It becomes `\numberlinegobble`, so something like `\numberline{1.1}` becomes

```
\numberline@gobble1.1\@nil
```

that in turn will yield `\noexpand\numberline{1}`. This will appear in `\protected@edef`, so `\noexpand` will disappear, but will also leave `\numberline` untouched. It will be processed by `titletoc` with its own definition.

Comment: Seems great! What would be the code if I want the `1.1` instead of `1` for section numbering?

Comment: @azetina Comment out the lines between `% redefine \numberline` and `% the minitoc proper`

Comment: Ok great. One more question? How can I fix the paragraph settings of the section definition since the word Statistics does not align with Algebra nor does long with Some? :)